# Does Bishop-Phelps Theorem hold for extreme points (slightly different version)?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

[Recall the Bishop-Phelps Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Phelps_theorem).

> **Bishop-Phelps Theorem:** Let $B\subseteq E$ be a bounded, closed, convex subset of a real Banach space $E.$
>   Then the set 
>   $$\{e^*\in E^*: e^* \text{ attains its supremum on } B \}$$
>   is norm-dense in the dual $E^*.$

Does the theorem hold for extreme points (slightly different version)? 
More precisely,

> *Question:* Let $B\subseteq E$ be a bounded, closed and convex subset of a real Banach space $E.$
>   Is it true that the set 
>   $$\{e^*\in\text{ext} \left( B_{E^*} \right): e^*(e) = \|e\|\text{ for some }e\in B\}$$
>   norm-dense in $\text{ext}\left( B_{E^*} \right)?$

If there is an affirmative answer to my question, may I have reference?

---

*Notation:* $E^*$ is the conjugate space.  $B_{E^*}$ is the closed unit ball of $E^*$.  We say that $e^*$ is an extreme point of $B_{E^*}$ if it cannot be expressed as midpoint of two elements from $B_{E^*}.$
Denote $\text{ext}\left( B_{E^*}\right)$ to be the set of all extreme points of $B_{E^*}.$

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler $B_{E^*}$ is the closed unit ball of $E^*,$ that is, $B_{E^*} = \{ e^*\in E^*: \|e^*\|\leq 1 \}$ where $\|e^*\|=\sup_{\|e\|\leq 1}|e^*(e)|.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $B$ is a bounded convex set that doesn't contain $0$, the Hahn-Banach separation theorem says there are $e^* \in E^*$ with $\| e^*\| = 1$ and $\epsilon > 0$ with $e^*(e) < -\epsilon$ for all $e \in B$; moreover, this is true (maybe with a smaller $\epsilon$) in a neighbourhood of $e^*$.  If $E^*$ is strictly convex, so every point of its unit sphere is an extreme point, your set is **not** dense in $\text{ext}(B_{E^*})$.